# Matching [],{},() in Mac

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard, mac-os-x

In the Windows system, the keyboard shortcuts

Matching [] <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
Matching {} <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>
Matching () <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>

works fine.

This functionality does not seem to work with MacOS.

<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> gives '
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> gives "
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> gives ‚

Is there any way to ensure the same functionality as Windows?

Comment: If I go Insert > Typesetting on my installation, I have Option + Command + Bracket. I don't think I've ever changed that so it might be the same on yours. It should also be possible to change re-bind these to other key combinations.

Comment: Thanks @MassDefect, I'll open a case in Wolfram so they update the help documentation accordingly.